# cropping netcdf file and plotting

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, rgdal

I am trying to plot the mixed layer depth by month for a given location.

Datafile: http://www.ifremer.fr/cerweb/deboyer/mld/Surface_Mixed_Layer_Depth.php 
Its the last file on the page but any file would work for now.

```
remove(list=ls())
library(raster)


mld <- brick("/Users/mld_DReqDTm02_c1m_reg2.0.nc", stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "mld")
print(mld)
extent(mld) <- extent(0, 360, -90, 90)
mld[mld > 1e4] <- NA
mld180 <- rotate(mld)
names(mld180) = month.abb

pprj <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=180 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0, 0, 0"
```

This is where I crop the data but im not sure if im doing it correctly. It works when I need to give it wide lat and Lon but I want to give it just one coordinate 61 degrees south to 65 degrees south and 140 degrees east I get an error and it won't plot.

```
g4 <- rgeos::gBuffer(SpatialPoints(cbind(0, 0), proj4string = CRS(pprj)), 
                 width = spDists(rbind(c(-140, -65), c(-140, -61)), longlat = TRUE, segments = T) * 1000, 
                 quadsegs = 180)



target <- projectExtent(mld180, pprj)
 Warning message:
 In rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  :
 48 projected point(s) not finite



mld_trans <- crop(projectRaster(mld180, target, CRS(pprj)), g4)
mld_trans <- mask(mld_trans, g4)

boxplot(mld_trans,las = 1, xlab="Month", ylab="MLD (m)")
```

What am I doing wrong and How can I crop the data to just this location and then plot the depth by month?

Answer (score 1):

Download file, open it and fix it (following your example)

```
url <- "http://www.ifremer.fr/cerweb/deboyer/data/mld_DReqDTm02_c1m_reg2.0.nc"
download.file(url, basename(url), mode="wb")  
library(raster)
mld <- brick("mld_DReqDTm02_c1m_reg2.0.nc", stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "mld")
extent(mld) <- extent(0, 360, -90, 90)
mld[mld > 1e4] <- NA
mld180 <- rotate(mld)
names(mld180) = month.abb
```

The easiest way to crop this is by creating an extent. Note that the min and max `x` cannot both be -140. Given that the data have a 2 degree spatial resolution, you get one column with -140 to -138, or with -142 to -140. I also adjusted the y limits (you would get the same with (-65, -61) --- as crop snaps the values to the grid cell boundaries)

```
e <- extent(-140, -138, -64, -60)
x <- crop(mld180, e)
```

If you want to use another crs you can now do

```
pprj <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=180 +datum=WGS84"
mld_trans <- projectRaster(x, crs=pprj, method="ngb")
```

Comment: I didn't know that we could download files from a url, thank you!  I get an error running the code. After the mld_trans line I get: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"character"’
In addition: Warning message:
In min(dim(to)[1:2]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf                  So when I try boxplot(mld_trans,las = 1, xlab="Month", ylab="MLD (m)") I get Error in boxplot(mld_trans, las = 1, xlab = "Month", ylab = "MLD (m)") : 
  object 'mld_trans' not found. I don't understand the problem..

Comment: Sorry, that last line was missing `crs=`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately mld_trans now comes up with no values. min values and max values are all NA for every month...

Comment: This is a bit of  a corner-case with a raster with only 1 column making the projection go wrong when using bilenear interpolation. It works with nearest neighbor. See the edited answer.

Comment: I still get the error object 'mld_trans' not found. Im going through and trying to understand each line of code. names(mld180) = month.abb gives an error Error in names(mld180) = month.abb : names() applied to a non-vector. Then when I try to crop x <- crop(mld180, e) I get another error Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crop’ for signature ‘"CoordFlip"’. So when I run mld_trans <- projectRaster(x, crs=pprj, method="ngb") says the Error in methods::extends(class(x), "BasicRaster") : object 'x' not found. Could it be my Mac?